# C# Webservice : Interface definition and web.config troubles

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I am working on a webservice. When I try to launch it from visualstudio2013, i now get this error : "Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata."

Does someone have a potential solution ?

Here is the interface of this webservice :

```
namespace WebService
{
[ServiceContract]
interface IWebService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
                                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
                                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
                                UriTemplate = "/tasks")]
    List<SwitanceTask> getTasks(string groupD, DateTime date);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
                               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                               UriTemplate = "/time")]
    DateTime getWebServiceTime();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
                                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
                                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                                UriTemplate = "/upd")]
    int updateTask(SwitanceTask task);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
                               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                               UriTemplate = "/grp")]
    List<SwitanceGroup> getGroups();

}}
```

And this is my configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="baseAdress" value="http://localhost:59074/wse"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
  </system.web>


  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="metadata" name="WebService.Service">
        <endpoint address="/tasks" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="tasks"
          contract="WebService.IWebService" />
        <endpoint address="/time" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="time"
          contract="WebService.IWebService" />
        <endpoint address="/upd" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="upd"
          contract="WebService.IWebService" />
        <endpoint address="/grp" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="grp"
          contract="WebService.IWebService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:59074/wse" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="metadata">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>


    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>



</configuration>
```

Comment: Is your WCF Service project running like in IIS / IIS Express

Comment: It is running in IIS Express (default option in visual studio).

Comment: yes, I meant to check if the WCF Project is part of your solution or is hosted separately elsewhere